# The meaning of “afterlift”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From "Butcher's Crossing" by John Williams:

> "The faint **afterlift** of a smile hung on Francine's full, pale lips; she nodded; her hand moved softly, soothingly, over his bare chest."

[[*Butcher's Crossing by John Williams*]](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIsdDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Butcher%27s%20Crossing&pg=PT200#v=onepage&q=afterlift&f=false)

What does "afterlift" mean here?

Comment: The writing seems competent enough, but 'afterlift' doesn't to have attained word status. Perhaps a typo for 'afterlife' (though this would be clumsy) for 'remains'. Perhaps an attempted coining that proved counterfeit (it's had 80 years to be accepted into the lexicon).

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though the author has invented the word.

When you smile, the corners of your mouth 'lift', so presumably he means that Francine had been smiling and the last trace of the expression was still visible on her face.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to follow the pattern of **afterglow**.

> OED: **Afterglow**
>
> **2.a. The remnant or residue of something;** (now esp.) a pleasant feeling remaining after a successful or happy experience.
>
> 1960   Victorian Stud. 3 332   *Writing in the afterglow of evolutionary theory, Frazer saw religion and magic as a kind of primitive science.*

or

> **afterburn, n.**
>
> **1. A lingering burning sensation. In later use esp.: a warm sensation in the mouth or throat caused by hot or spicy food or strong alcoholic drink.**
>
> 1992   Texas Monthly Jan. 160/2   *Spicy chicken, studded with scallions and green peppers and heaped with peanuts, is tender and deceptively warm, with a satisfying afterburn.*

i.e. something that remains after the main action of the verbal noun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like a word invented by the author, the 'lift' of a smile on the face combined with afterlife to create afterlift, he seems to want to say that the smile was there, but faint like a ghost